# Passing parameters to the constructor of a class which is a member of another class

Tags: c++, class, parameters, constructor

I have class called Bar,
and in this class Bar there is an object of type Foo (a class).
Class Bar takes 3 parameters, x, y and z. Foo takes 2 parameters, y and z.

currently I'm doing this:

```
class Bar {
 public:
  Bar(int x, int y, int z) { 
      foo = new Foo(y, z);
      do something with x;
  }

 private:
  Foo * foo;
};
```

I remember seeing in a book another way to do this using a colon but I don't remember how exactly.

What is the standard or usual way of doing something like this?

Comment: Foo is a container class and contains a vector of type myClass. When I do this I now get the error:
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\vector(1541): error C2036: 'myClass *' : unknown size

It compiled and ran fine when I did it using dynamic allocation.

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Are you forward-declaring the class? You can do that for pointers and references, but the compiler needs the full definition (read: header) for a plain member.

Answer (score 6):

Use an [initializer list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html) and avoid dynamic allocation:

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(int x, int y, int z) : foo(y, z) {}
private:
    Foo foo;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Bar {
 public:
  Bar(int x, int y, int z) : foo(y, z) { 
      do something with x;
  }

 private:
  Foo foo;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your perplexing line should be

```
... 
Bar(int x, int y, int z) : foo(new Foo(y,z)) { 
... 
private: 
Foo* foo; 
...
```

i see other answers dont use pointer. But correct one should be this.

Comment: If by "correct" you mean "preserving the unnecessary dynamic allocation and memory leak", then you're right. Personally, I prefer the answers that recommended avoiding dynamic allocation.

Comment: I tried to stick to the original question. I saw a pointer type `Foo` then used a pointer initialization because we dont know the internal structure of `Foo`. Maybe there are link lists and the user want to do `foo = foo->next;` in somewhere.Besides it is good to learn preferring non-pointer objects is a common practice.

Comment: @FredrickGauss Yes, they're pretty dangerous really. If you want some good info, look up 'RAII'.